# How do I use the csv module to add a column?

Tags: python, list, csv

I've got a csv file with a matrix of data. When the initial csv file is opened in Notepad it looks like this:

"AAA,15.0"
"BBB,45.0"
"CCC,60.0"

I then want to process this data, adding another column to get something formatted as follows:

"AAA,15.0,50.0"
"BBB,45.0,30.0"
"CCC,60.0,20.0"

So.......
I open the original file into Python using:

```
with open((FilePath"/XXX.csv"), 'rt') as csvfile:
   NewData = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';'))

print(NewData)
```

The first time I do this the code produces a list of strings (which I'm actually happy about - I want this format)...

['AAA,15.0,50.0', 'BBB,45.0,30.0', 'CCC,60.0,20.0']

But then next time I try to add a column I end up with....

[['AAA,15.0,50.0'], ['BBB,45.0,30.0'], ['CCC,60.0,20.0']]

So, each time my code runs it adds an additional layer of 'listing'.

What do I need to do to keep the initial formatting of a list of strings? I imagine it's because I'm opening the file with the list() command. What should I be using?

---

Further details as requested.........

Distilling this further...My code is...

```
import csv

FilePathSB="C:/Users/"

with open((FilePathSB+"/Master.csv"), 'rt') as csvfile:

   xMatrix = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';'))

####Do something to the data like add another column of numbers                                                      

#SaveAs same file

with open(FilePathSB+"/Master.csv", "w") as output:
   writer=csv.writer(output,lineterminator='\n')
   for val in xMatrix:
      writer.writerow([val])
```

Note that there is some data manipulation that occurs while the file is open but this doesn't impact the problem I have so I've left the code out.

Opening the file and then saving it is adding a layer of 'listing' each time the code runs. I'd like the formatting to remain unchanged (ie so despite being opened and then resaved I'd like the data format to be the same as the initial matrix shown below).

So the first time the code runs it opens the initial csv data of:

```
"AAA,24:17"
"BBB,21:18"
"CCC,16:40"
```

and changes the format to saves it as:

```
"['AAA,24:17']"
"['BBB,21:18']"
"['CCC,16:40']"
```

If I run the code again it takes this data and changes it to:

```
"[""['AAA,24:17']""]"
"[""['BBB,21:18']""]"
"[""['CCC,16:40']""]"
```

And if I run it again I end up with:

```
"['[""[\'AAA,24:17\']""]']"
"['[""[\'BBB,21:18\']""]']"
"['[""[\'CCC,16:40\']""]']"
```

Comment: I think we also need to see how you're writing to the file.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by "the next time".  There are no loops in your code, so this will only run once. Also not clear what you are "adding a column to", or how.  The file?  The list?  Make sure you're showing us all the relevant code.

Comment: I think we can all agree we need to see the other relevant parts of the code (or at least sample code representing them)

Comment: The issue appears to be that you're creating a list from the data you're reading (you're calling `list()` on your reader object). You should try appending the data itself to your list instead.

Comment: I don't see any semicolon (;) in your sample data. Why are you using it as a delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

The csv Reader is meant to parse your file row by row, and return a list for each one.
If we had a file like:

```
header1|header2
      1|      A
      2|      B
```

when we parsed this csv file using the "|" character as a delimiter, we'd get:

```
[['header1', 'header2'], ['1', 'A'], ['2', 'B']]
```

This is exactly what we're supposed to expect in this case. However, if we parsed it with some other character as the delimiter, we'd still get:

```
[['header1|header2'], ['1|    A'], ['2|    B']]
```

This is what you're doing, because your csv reader is primed to expect a delimiter of ";", while your actual csv has (apparently) a delimiter of ",".

After reading your csv in using reader, you'll have a list of lists, where each inner list represents a row.  Think of it as looking like this:

```
[
 row1,
 row2,
 row3
]
```

where each row looks like:

```
[cell1, cell2, cell3]
```

If you want to add a new column to each row, you'll have to iterate over all the rows:

```
for current_row in rows:
    # use current row here
```

and use the .append() method of a list to add the new column.

```
    current_row.append('new_value')
```

Finally, you can use csv.writer to write your rows to another file. See [csv.writerows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows)